Autogenerate DTO classes?
Yesterday I screwed up:
One of the classes of my C# contained a property, called "DeliverdQuantity" (yep, there's a spelling mistake indeed). When I saw that, I decided to correct that, replacing the name of the property all over the application, and I thought I had done a good thing.
However, I was not aware of the presence of another class (the DTO), also containing that same property (with the spelling mistake), and as both objects are mapped together, using some automatic mapper, the value of the property did not get filled, causing a bug at customer premises.
Hereby an example of that mapping: objSectionDto = _mapper.Map<SectionDto>(objSection);.
My boss was convinced that I had done a bad thing and that the usage of DTO objects is good practice, but I'm not!

First I don't see the need of using DTO objects: in my company DTO classes are just the regular classes, stripped from there methods. Those DTO classes get serialised and the information gets sent over and forth, and that's all. If it would be possible to serialise the original class (maybe it is), then I don't see the need for DTO objects.
Second: imagine that the usage of DTO classes can be justified: in that case they MUST be auto-generated (during compilation), in order for mistakes like mine to be avoided. How can this be achieved? (We are working with Visual Studio 2022)

Am I right and in case not, where am I wrong?
Thanks in advance

The real red flag to me here is the apparent lack of testing between you making a change and the code being deployed to a customer.

@PhilipKendall: although afterwards it seems obvious that testing was needed, it's not that simple: my modification consisted of renaming a property, which, in a normal situation, is similar to renaming a variable, which also does not cause any harm: the only way renaming a variable can cause harm, is by renaming it to a name which already exists, and that will cause your code not to compile. So if you rename a variable and your code compiles, everything is ok, which is exactly what I expected here.

@PhilipKendall: in top of that, the but I mentioned was in the display. My company does not do any structured unit testing or module testing, and there is no regression testing too. But even if those basic forms of testing were present, even then GUI displays generally are not part of testing procedures, so it would not be detected anyway.

"GUI displays generally are not part of testing procedures" They should be part of integration testing

"So if you rename a variable and your code compiles, everything is ok" That is honestly a rather naive view of the world, especially in languages with reflection capabilities.

@PhilipKendall: I started programming in Delphi/Pascal (1998), then went to C and Java (2002-2017), never really upgrading to the more recent versions, so indeed, my career did not really send me across languages with reflection capabilities :-)

@Dominique: "although afterwards it seems obvious that testing was needed, it's not that simple: my modification consisted of renaming a property, which, in a normal situation, is similar to renaming a variable, which also does not cause any harm" The point of testing is not to accurately predict what future mistakes you will make and only write tests for those expected scenarios and nothing else. The point of testing is to provide an automated fact checker that confirms that you didn't break any of the required behavior.

@Dominique "if you rename a variable and your code compiles, everything is ok" Your entire scenario in this question is exactly one where you renamed something, it compiled, and it was not okay. You now arguing that this should be okay is an act of refusing to acknowledge reality.

"First I don't see the need of using DTO objects" Making such broad-sweeping statement against a widespread good practice guideline, and doing it offhandedly without even investigating whether or not that opinion follows the accepted convention, is a really concerning part of this question. This, combined with the dismissal of the value of testing and its methodology (in comments) suggests that you're operating under certain immovable beliefs that do not align with current conventions and standards surrounding good practice coding. What is it you're trying to get out of this question?

@Flater: as observed by your colleague Philip Kendall, I have a career in working with languages without reflection capabilities, leading to my question. Nothing wrong with that.

@Dominique: I'm not calling out you being unfamiliar with some things. I'm calling out your lack of investigating the things you're not familiar with and seeing if there's a bigger picture you might be missing. The same is true of your mention on what testing could(n't) have done here. There is a distinct lack of ingesting the given advice, instead immediately responding how it doesn't fit in your current view on things. I'm not pointing this out to berate, I'm pointing this out because fighting the advice you're being given will make the learning journey so much harder on you.

@Dominique If you're as unfamiliar with the tech stack as you've mentioned, which is perfectly fine, I recommend taking a more humble approach to learning on how to work with the new stack. Don't assume that approaches different from yours aren't going to work for you, because that inhibits learning. There's a reason why some people say you can't teach an old dog new tricks, and you're sort of being that old dog here. Again, I'm pointing this out because I genuinely believe that you're possibly doing this subconsciously and that awareness might help you sidestep that obstacle to learning.

@Flater: I'm not against learning at all. It's just that I have learned decades ago about how compilers work, and I have seen the assembler code of a piece of C-code where the names of the variables were not even mentioned. Having seen this has caused with me the certainty that variable names can be changed without any problems. Now, while working with a language with reflection capabilities, this "all time truth" seems not to be a truth anymore. I find this very interesting, but also very worrysome: what other "all time truths" are also not true anymore? (I'm not reluctant, I'm scared)

Before we start
In the comments to your question, it was established that you're coming from a significantly older tech stack and are unfamiliar with newer paradigms. That's perfectly fine, and I'll do my best to phrase this answer from that perspective - I'm pre-emptively sorry if I end up overexplaining something that you're already familiar with because I know that can come across as patronizing. It's not my intention, I'm just trying to address anything you might not be aware of to help paint the bigger picture.
If you don't care about the more verbose explanation, I'll just give you a bullet point solution at the bottom. However, I strongly suggest you read this because I believe your lack of familiarity is a major contributor to the root cause, and the long answer is written specifically to make you more familiar with the tools you're using.

The DTO "pattern"

My boss was convinced that I had done a bad thing and that the usage of DTO objects is good practice, but I'm not!

The underlying assertion that drove you to ask this question is that you drove your car into a tree, and are now going to the car dealership to complain about
the faulty car you were given to drive.
Consider the possibility that it was the driver who was at fault, not the car.
That's not an irredeemable judgment on you as a developer, but what I'm seeing in your story is that mistakes were made that are not necessarily marks against the general practice of encapsulating a layer by using mapped DTOs. Your question, however, shuts out that possibility, instead pursuing a discussion on how the pattern is definitely the one in the wrong.
For the purpose of not writing half a book, I'm going to sidestep the basic "why do we create DTOs" explanation for now. There are many, many resources on the topic and me parroting them doesn't add much value. Here is an excellent writeup on the topic, take special note of the "Reasons to Use DTOs" section, which highlights the benefits well.

Incident post mortem
I'm going to dissect the events and point out everything that went into creating the problem. This isn't meant to persecute, it's meant to highlight what went into the issue so that we can address how to prevent it in the future.

However, I was not aware of the presence of another class (the DTO)

A lack of awareness is a dangerous thing for a developer making changes in a codebase. Now, in your defense, you're not wrong that with DTO abstractions, you should indeed be able to refactor something internally without impacting the external API, and that seems to be how you went about things.
Lesson: Familiarize yourself with the codebase so you can identify impacted areas when you make a change in the codebase.
I'm bringing this up to contrast it to the following point:

Hereby an example of that mapping:
objSectionDto = _mapper.Map<SectionDto>(objSection);

AutoMapper (which I'm inferring this is, based on the syntax and what went wrong here) is a tool whose predominant purpose is to help you avoid writing menial boilerplate mapping logic when a domain model and DTO are virtually identical and the same-name properties obviously map to eachother one-to-one.
AutoMapper has more features than that, but the "auto" in the name is usually what gets people to start using the library.
This is done using reflection. Reflection is nifty, but it can be argued to be a dirty hack around the strong typing and integrity that the compiler is supposed to provide by refusing to build an application that doesn't work.
This already gets us to our first potential solution. Based on how you approached the change you were making, and how you were clearly relying on the compiler to find the issue for you; you probably shouldn't have relied on reflection then, because reflection disables the compiler's ability to second-guess you. Had you written a manual mapping, i.e.:
public class SectionMapper : ISectionMapper
{
    public SectionDto ToSectionDto(Section section)
        => new SectionDto()
           {
               DeliverdQuantity = section.DeliveredQuantity
           };
}

... then you wouldn't have run into the problem (notice that I fixed the name of the internal Section but not that of the SectionDto). You wouldn't have even needed to look at this mapping. A blind F2 refactor would have updated the right hand side (section.DeliveredQuantity) and left the left hand side untouched, which is what you wanted.
Lesson: by explicitly mapping your objects, property by property, the compiler is able to call you out on any mistakes you make here.
But there were more possible solutions here.
I don't want to delve into an entire diatribe on the value of testing, but your scenario has a clear testing gap in it. Tests exist specifically to catch deviations from the intended behavior and bugs that you introduce during refactoring. This is precisely what happened to you, and you had no tests to catch you out.
I'll skip the lecture on testing, but here's a good writeup to explain the main benefits.
Lesson: Pre-emptively writing appropriate tests (before any bug occurs) helps you identify anything you may end up breaking during a refactor (or feature extension).
I have to admit, the problem you faced was a very subtle one, and it's very easy to make the mistake that you did, when AutoMapper runs around the compiler by using reflection. AutoMapper is aware of this, and has tools to help you. Take a look at their documentation on configuration validation.
The example scenario is exactly your problem scenario: an unintended discrepancy between the source and target property name. To help combat this, AutoMapper has a AssertConfigurationIsValid method which will explicitly call out if it finds any property for which it cannot source the needed information (i.e. because the source type does not have an automatically mappable property available).
You could write a single unit test which simply generates your entire application's mapper configuration, and then call AssertConfigurationIsValid on it. If any mapping breaks, your test will fail and you will be made aware of it.
Note that this doesn't catch every possible issue. It only catches issues when the target type contains a property that AutoMapper does not know how to source from the source type, i.e. there is no explicit mapping defined and there is nothing that the auto-logic can make sense of.
Personally, I also perform this check during application startup in DEBUG mode. This means that when I run my app locally, I'm already made aware that I broke something. I don't run it in RELEASE mode because I don't want the entire application to blow up in production just because one mapping broke (it's better to have everything else still work and have it only blow up for the actually broken bits only when they're used).
Lesson: Familiarizing yourself with the tools you're using would have helped you identify that AutoMapper is very aware of the issue you encountered and already provided tooling for you to help avoid this issue altogether.

The XY problem

Imagine that the usage of DTO classes can be justified: in that case they MUST be auto-generated (during compilation), in order for mistakes like mine to be avoided. How can this be achieved?

This is the Y in your XY problem. You're barely entertaining the idea that DTO layering makes sense, but on the hypothesis that it does, you are asserting that it must invariably be auto-generated, and now your question is pursuing how to autogenerate DTOs.
Your train of thought has gone off the rails, into the mountainside, and you're asking how to make this train scale the mountain, instead of trying to get it back on the track (and identifying how it managed to leave the track in the first place to avoid it happening again).
Auto-generating defeats the purpose of DTOs. Referring back to the resource I linked, the purpose of a DTO is to provide the ability for the DTO to diverge from the domain model, i.e. the ability to make a change in one without necessarily needing to change the other.
If you auto-generate your DTO, you are effectively mandating that your DTO always matches your domain model, at which point you've defeated the purpose of having a DTO in the first place.
It also would not have solved the problem, it would have created a different problem. Someone is consuming this DTO. They have an expectation that the field name is DeliverdQuantity. By having a mirrored DTO, when you fixed your domain model, you inherently also changed that property name on the DTO. This will have broken your consumer's code.
This touches on the purpose of having the DTO in the first place: the ability to fix an internal issue without impacting the external consumer. If you needed to avoid breaking changes in your consumers at all costs, a DTO would make that possible for you. Refer back to the explicit mapping snippet I wrote, where you can see that the internal domain model is fixed, while at the same time the external API has been intentionally left untouched so as to avoid introducing a breaking change.
public class SectionMapper : ISectionMapper
{
    public SectionDto ToSectionDto(Section section)
        => new SectionDto()
           {
               DeliverdQuantity = section.DeliveredQuantity
           };
}


Conclusion - what you could have done differently

Familiarity with the whole codebase is paramount if you're going to be making changes to the existing code. A developer needs to be able to identify impacted areas when introducing changes.
If you intend to heavily rely on the compiler to catch your mistakes for you, favor writing explicit code and avoid reflection.
Back your code with unit tests to catch regressions and bugs in your application behavior (note that mapping logic falls under application behavior).
When using a tool, read the documentation on that tool to learn about common pitfalls and suggested solutions to these pitfalls
Identify when you fall into the trap of XY problems, and learn to take a step back and identify any blind assumptions you may be making, so as to avoid relying on them going forward.


You are right.
DTOs are not needed unless you have classes with calculated properties and or private properties. They are a consequence of "Classic OOP" design. ie
public class Person
{
   public string Name {get; private set;}
   public int Age {
      get {
        return (DateTime.Now - this.dob).TotalYears;
      }
}

It's hard to send this class over the wire because

The properties can't be set directly, you will need some custom deserialisation code
The calculated field needs the date of birth, which is not sent at all

In regards to autogenerating, I think not. Say you had some auto generating code that worked for all classes, wouldn't that be the same as being able to serialise the class? You wouldn't need the DTO anymore.
If you can easily write an auto dto generator because it just removes methods, then you don't need DTOs
A DTO is the custom code that lets a standard serialiser serialise your difficult to serialise class. If you have a difficult to serialise class you can either make a DTO and send that, doing the transformation on each side, or add some custom de/serialisation code
Re: Testing
I would suggest you write a custom assert which loops through all the properties of an object and asserts each is not null. You can use this in your Integration tests to pick up on stuff like this, where there is a partial failure of serialisation, wrong column in sql, wrong class deserialised to etc

Looping through all properties of an object? How can this be done? (As Philip Kendall already pointed out, I'm not that strong in using the reflection capabilities of a language)

i dont have sample code to hand, but its pretty easy : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151888/c-sharp-iterate-through-class-properties

Indeed: once you know there's something, like typeof(someObject).GetProperties();, it becomes rather easy :-)

The opening points made about not needing DTOs are skimming the fact that this additional layer of abstraction affords you the ability to alter your internal implementation or your (external) API model, without needing to invariably be forced to refactor the other. That has nothing to do with calculated or hard to get/set values; but rather the ability for the DTO to diverge from the internal model even if they start out looking the same. It is much, much harder to introduce a DTO down the line when the two models do end up diverging, than it is to introduce it from the get go.

I would class a lot of that as View Model, rather than DTO. I would say its an anti pattern when the lines get blurred. For a SPA you want the model at the front end to compose into viewmodels

Dto’s like their close cousins ViewModels don’t need to be and should not be, auto generated.  In both cases their value comes in part from a break from their source and in part from their customization.  A human has examined them and determined what is needed and what is not, and what it looks like.  For instance a telephone number may at one layer be a country code, area code, and a number (or even an alphanumeric), and at another level be a simple string.
Auto generating them as anything other than a template that will be modified just defeats the purpose of why you use them.
